# Java Pattern won't match given string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

```
Pattern.matches(regex, value);
```

returns `false` for the given Parameters:

```
Regex = [<>:/\\\\|?*] value = This Should /\Match*?
```

my expectation however is that it should return `true`, what am I missing here?

Comment: `matches` matches the whole string. Your regex matches 1 character.

Comment: And how do I get the expected result, if pattern should return `true` if *any* of these characters are within the string? @AndyTurner

Comment: `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).find()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner got it, thanks

Answer (score -1):

[`Pattern.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-):

> behaves in exactly the same way as the expression
>
> ```
> Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()
> ```

and [`Matcher.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--):

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

Your regex doesn't match the entire string.